# Redux infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { language: state.language, user: state.user};
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    initConfig: () => dispatch(initConfig())
  };
}
```

It's working fine, now I need to add some information about the ui and to do this I need to map another parts objects:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { language: state.language, user: state.user, userSettings: state.userSettings};
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    initConfig: () => dispatch(initConfig())
  };
}
```

If I add `userSettings: state.userSettings` the app do an infinite loop like that the settings change ever and the components need a reload, but this is not true, the components remain still the same, how it's possible? Why this re-render?

Here my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
 settings : {
    tags: false,
    userSettings: {
      active_socialization         : 0,
      active_socialization_radius  : 0,
      active_socialization_age_min : 0,
      active_socialization_age_max : 0,
      active_socialization_gender  : '',
      position_visibility          : 0,
      position_label               : '',
      notify_mention_post          : 0,
      notify_mention_photo         : 0,
      notify_new_post_follow       : 0,
      notify_new_post_hot          : 0,
      notify_new_post_moderate     : 0,
      notify_new_post_private      : 0,
      notify_new_post_group        : 0,
      visibility_username          : 0,
      visibility_contact           : 0,
      ui_bkg_type                  : false,
      ui_bkg_image                 : false,
      ui_color_photo               : false,
      ui_color_video               : false,
      ui_color_audio               : false,
      ui_color_minimes             : false,
      ui_color_news                : false,
      ui_color_mix                 : false
    }
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  // LOADING
  if (action.type === "UTILITY_LOADING") {
    console.log('reducer UTILIY_LOADING');
    return { ...state,   utility : { loading : true } }
  }

  // LANGUAGE
  if (action.type === "UTILITY_LANGUAGE") {
    console.log('reducer UTILITY_LANGUAGE');
    console.log(action);
    return { ...state, language : action.payload }
  } 

    // INIT CONFIG
  if (action.type === "INIT_CONFIG_LOADED") {
    return { ...state,  settings : { ...state.settings, tags : action.payload.tags, userSettings : action.payload.userSettings, appSettings : action.payload.appSettings, userRow : action.payload.userRow, avatar : action.payload.avatar } , utility : { loading : false, } }
  } 

  if (action.type === "INIT_CONFIG_NOT_LOADED") {
    return { ...state,   utility : { loading : false } }
  } 

...
```

Comment: can you show us how your userSettings reducer looks like?

Comment: where are you calling `initConfig()`?

Comment: It seems to be a call of `initConfig()` in some lifecycle method. Then your reducer returns a completely new state `{...state, ...}`. So, `connect` HOC updates your component and a lifecycle method is called again... and so on...  

Am I right? =)

Comment: there is no `userSettings` in `state.userSettings` - try `state.settings.userSettings`

Comment: Thanks to all @IvanBurnaev you're right, my mistake, I called initConfig also inside render, thank you, your answer put me on the right way to solve. If you want answer and not only comment I can set your answer as accepted.

Comment: @red it's not a big deal =) I'm glad to help!